# Sorting ArrayList of HashTables in Java

Tags: java, date, arraylist, hashmap, comparator

This is my first post. I'm a CS major doing and internship during my sophomore summer. I've had a good amount of experience with Java, but comparing objects has always given me trouble.

Right now I'm editing a JSP page that has a bunch of events on different days of the calendar.  Each event is a HashMap saved in an ArrayList (of events). I need to sort these events.

This is an example of how they are added.  There is a lot of logic because many of the dates were saved as reoccurring dates (ie. "First Sunday in May").

```
  convertedDate = convertJulian(rs.getDouble("starting_date"));
  eventDate = convertedDate.split(",");
  tempMap.put("id", rs.getString("cal_item_id"));
  tempMap.put("description", rs.getString("description"));            
  tempMap.put("startingDate", rs.getInt("starting_date"));    
  tempMap.put("resource", rs.getString("resource_name"));
  tempMap.put("eventMonth", eventDate[0]);
  tempMap.put("eventDay", eventDate[1]);
  tempMap.put("eventYear", eventDate[2]);

  if (!parkYearsList.contains(eventDate[2]) && rs.getDouble("starting_date") >= startDate) {
      parkYearsList.add(eventDate[2]);
  }
  if ( rs.getDouble("starting_date") >= startDate)            
      parkEventsList.add(tempMap);
```

To sort them, I tried doing this. But it deletes everything in the ArrayList?

```
Collections.sort(parkEventsList, new MapComparator() );
```

Here is my comparator and the `toJulian` method. I didn't write most of this, so its a little difficult to see where there could be problems.

```
public class MapComparator implements Comparator
{
    public int compare( Object object1 , Object object2)
    {

        String date1=(String)((HashMap)object1).get("startingDate");
        String date2=(String)((HashMap)object2).get("startingDate");

        Double date1Value = toJulian(date1);
        Double date2Value = toJulian(date2);

        return date1Value.compareTo(date2Value);
    }
}


public static double toJulian(String ymd) {
    String[] date = ymd.split(",");
    int jgreg = 15 + 31*(10+12*1582); 
    int year=Integer.parseInt(date[0]);
    int month=Integer.parseInt(date[1]); 
    int day=Integer.parseInt(date[2]);
    int julianYear = year;
    if (year < 0) julianYear++;
    int julianMonth = month;
    if (month > 2) {
        julianMonth++;
    }
    else {
        julianYear--;
        julianMonth += 13;
    }

    double julian = (java.lang.Math.floor(365.25 * julianYear)
         + java.lang.Math.floor(30.6001*julianMonth) + day + 1720995.0);
    if (day + 31 * (month + 12 * year) >= jgreg) {
        // change over to Gregorian calendar
        int ja = (int)(0.01 * julianYear);
        julian += 2 - ja + (0.25 * ja);
    }

    return java.lang.Math.floor(julian);
}
```

Comment: As a side note, you can add a generic type to a comparator

Comment: Your comparator seems fine. A call of `Collections.sort` cannot "delete everything from the `ArrayList`", no matter what the comparator does. The error is probably elsewhere.

Comment: Can you please post your toJulian method?

Comment: It works for me. I believe something is wrong with your data or code which has not been posted. Try to run it in debug mode. Is it possible that your array list stays empty because of rs.getDouble("starting_date") >= startDate condition?

Comment: Does your `MapComparator` have unit tests? If no, go write some. It will help isolate this problem and fix it faster than putzing around with it in the JSP/UI manually. I would create tests comparing several individual maps then a few with unsorted lists.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public static Hashtable<String, String> sortValue(Hashtable<String, String> t)
            {
               //Transfer as List and sort it
                 ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, String>> l = new ArrayList<Entry<String, String>>(t.entrySet());
                  Hashtable<String,String> f = new Hashtable<String,String>(); 
                  Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, String>>(){
                     public int compare(Map.Entry<String, String> o1, Map.Entry<String, String> o2) {
                    return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
             }});}
```